# Spring how to (de)activate complete packages by profile

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application. For a specific package of services i need to provide 2 different implementations (one using db one using HTTP API).

One set should be active by default and the other by setting a profile.

the package structure is:

```
 otherstuff 
 service
   dbimpl
   httpimpl
   <serviceinterfaces>
```

dbimpl (all classes in there) should be active by default and httpimpl should be activate by profile (that should deactivate dbimpl classes)

What is the easiest way to implement such an "switch"?

I thought about using `@ComponentScan` but i don't know how to switch between different Classes with component scan - i don't know how to have multiple classes with `@ComponentScan` and switch between them by profile.

I also don't want (at the moment worst option) to annotate each class with `Profile`.

So how to (de)activate complete packages by profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have something like

```
package org.example;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("org.example")
public class BootApplication {
}
```

1) Split your configuration into multiple classes and put them into separate nested package, say `org.example.config`

```
package org.example.config;

@Profile("default")
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("service.dbimpl")
public class DefaultConfig {
}
```

and

```
package org.example.config;

@Profile("!default")
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("service.httpimpl")
public class CustomConfig {
}
```

Assuming `default` is the name of default profile. It could be set up in `application.properties` file

```
spring.profiles.active=default
```

2) Replace global component scan in SpringBoot application with a less global one

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("org.example.config")  // instead of "org.example"
public class BootApplication {
}
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, since i am using spring boot: all begins with spring boot mainclass - at the moment annotated with @SpringBootApplication (scans includes all). I guess i have to change this some how to include at least one Configuration?! How the main class must be annotated?

Comment: i guess i regards to my example structure package "otherstuff" is not available with your answer, but this i could find out my self i guess :-)